# Telerik basic question

Tags: javascript, frameworks, telerik

I've just come across a website on our intranet and found that on every page click it downloads a different set of JavaScript frameworks (like jQuery) and compiles them all into one file. They are quite large (600k-900k) and with a unique identifier, these are never cached.

This confuses and concerns me. Is it really downloading almost a MB of JavaScript on every new page? Or is there some kind of funky caching happening that I'm not aware of?

Comment: can you post your version of telerik? are you using the RadControls or RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, would it say it at the top of the JavaScript? I'm not the owner of the server or website but I do have to verify it is a "good website" and a MB of JavaScript thats never cached does put a bit of a question mark over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of the RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX have CDN support - you will get all the scripts from the Amazon CloudFront content delivery service. If they are using embedded resources for the scripts (ScriptResource.axd, Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd) then make sure that the site is running in release mode (<compilation> element in Web.Config). Finally, if the site is using the RadScriptManager control and combines all scripts into one request, it is possible that each page has a different set of controls, so the combined request will be different. This means that it will be downloaded at least once on each page until all possible control configurations are exhausted. After that the script content should be cached in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense and it gives me a starting place.